# how to check if elements are not the selected one

Tags: jquery, html

I am looking for a jQuery method how to check if a specific element is not one of the others.
This is a general question because the way I did it before was the following.

Let's say I have a Menu-bar with 5 buttons and I want to fire something if a button is clicked I do

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
   $(this).css('color','blue');
   $('#button2').css('color','red');
   $('#button3').css('color','red');
   $('#button4').css('color','red'); 
}

$('#button2').click(function() {
   $(this).css('color','blue');
   $('#button1'.css('color','red');
   $('#button3').css('color','red');
   $('#button4').css('color','red'); 
} // and so on for #button3, 4 ...
```

this works, of course. But it seems to much code for a few Buttons. And the question is, how can I ask something like:

```
$(this).click(function() {
  $(this).css('color','blue');
  $(all others).css('color','red'); }
```

Do I have to use Arrays, or is there a jQuery solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: giving class to your buttons seems easy enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of working with ids add a common class for all related buttons then

```
var $btns = $('.mybuttons').click(function(){
    $(this).css('color','blue');
    $btns.not(this).css('color','red'); 
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TcZw5/)

Update:

```
$('body').on('click', '.sublink', function () {
    $(this).css('color', '#393fad');
    $('.sublink').not(this).css('color', '#8b8b8b');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AdSh4/)

Comment: this seems the best solution to me. the `.not()` selector is what I was searching for. Thank you for this!

Comment: can I ask you how to use this with `.on()` delegate?

`var $btns = $('body').on('click', '.sublink', function(){
    $(this).css('color','#393fad');
    $btns.not(this).css('color','#8b8b8b'); 
 })`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[attributes-starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)**

```
 $(this).click(function() {
    $('[id^="button"]').css('color','red');   
    $(this).css('color','blue');
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase they are all in the same div like this you can use `.siblings()`

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div button').on('click', function () {
        $(this).css('color', 'blue').siblings().css('color', 'red');
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
<button id="button1">test1</button>
<button id="button2">test2</button>
<button id="button3">test3</button>
<button id="button4">test4</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first make all button's color red.
take a common class

```
 $('.all_button').click(function() {
    $('.all_button').css('color','red');
    $(this).css('color','blue');
)};
```

i think this should work.

Comment: this won't work because if one button is clicked it stays blue. But only the selected should be blue, the other ones return to red.